# Running code in a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0

In c# 4, how can I run a piece of code in a separate thread?

I only want to execute a "Save to recent used" without impacting the main thread.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Adil I really love the TPL library, but man, it is so wrong here. When someone asks how do get a taxi you also do not expond witha guideline how to run a txi company, or?

Comment: I think that link has quite straight forward examples right from the start.

Comment: Why was my question down voted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `Task`

class,

```
Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine("I'm executing on the threadpool"));
```

Comment: +1. As simple as it gets. Note that this does not create a thread but uses the threadpool in the most likely implementation. THe whole thread thing is abstracted.

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to both c# and Stackoverflow.

Comment: And, what is the difference between the two answers?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { 
    //What ever code you like...
});
```